# How do I remove space at the end of an output in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a program that counts and prints all words in a sentence that contains a specific character(ignoring case).

Code in Python -

```
item=input()
ip=input().tolower()
r=ip.count(item)
print(r)
ip=ip.split()
for word in ip:
    if item in word:
        print((word), end=' ')
```

This program works as expected but for the last word that is printed I don't want a white-space after it. 
[image]

If anyone could guide me on how to remove the space it would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, please, please copy (Ctrl-C) and paste (Ctrl-V) your code and output into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)?

```
print(' '.join([w for w in ip if item in w]))
```

Comment: Better yet, let `print` do the joining for you: `print(*[w for w in ip if item in w])` This uses a *splat* to unpack the list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to remove that, as it's a part of your terminal. Best answer I can give you.

I expanded on the code though, cause I was kinda bored.

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ").lower()
pull = input("Which character(s) do you want to count?: ").lower()
for c in pull:
    occurrences = 0
    for character in sentence:
        if c == character:
            occurrences+=1
    if c!=" ": print("\'%s\' appears %d times"%(c, occurrences))
    for word in sentence.split():
        occurrences = 0
        for character in word:
            if c == character:
                occurrences+=1
        if occurrences == 1:
            print(("1 time in \'%s\'")%(word))
        elif occurrences > 0:
            print(("%d times in \'%s\'")%(occurrences,word))
```

Answer (score 0):

+The solution with a list comprehension appears more concise, but if you prefer an alternative you can use the following. It was tested and worked with the example in the picture.

```
# Amended solution. The commented lines are the amendment.
item = input('Letter: ')
ip = input('Input: ').lower()
r = ip.count(item)
print(r)
ip = ip.split()
outputString = '' # Added: Initialise an empty string to keep the answer
for word in ip:
    if item in word:
        outputString += word + ' '  # Changed: Accumulates the answer in a string
print(outputString[:-1])  # Added: Prints all the string's characters
                          # except the last one, which is the additional space
```

Answer (score -1):

You're close, just change your print statement from `print((word), end=' ')` to `print((word), end='')`. Your print statement has a whitespace for the end but you don't want the whitespace so make the end an empty string.

Comment: When I change to... print((word), end='') ...it removes the spaces in the sentence as well. How am I supposed to write it so that it only removes the whitespace at the end and not the spaces between the words.