# How do I get rid of a whitespace at the end of an output while maintaining to print in the same line? (rstrip() didnt work)

Tags: python

```
data = {} #open dictionary
data.update({" " : "/"})
with open("morsecode.txt", "r") as f: #read file
  for line in f: #read each line
    key, value = line.split() #split key and value
    data[key] = value #define key and value
#print(data) # test if dictionary work

msg = input("Message: ").upper() # reads user input
for letter in msg: #for every letter in the message
  print(data[letter],end =" ") #output
```

The objective is to convert an input by the user into morse code, seperating the letters by a "
/". Basically my program does print out the code right, but not in the same line. I tried using ,end=" ". However, the output now has a white space at the end which I want to avoid. I tried using rstrip() but then there are no spaces inbetween my letters.

The output is:

```
Message: My iPad died.
-- -.-- / .. .--. .- -.. / -.. .. . -.. .-.-.- (theres a white space at the end)
```

Instead of:

```
Message: My iPad died.
-- -.-- / .. .--. .- -.. / -.. .. . -.. .-.-.- (no whitespace at the end)
```

Comment: What do you mean with `rstrip()` doesn't work ? It should

Comment: You're printing with `end=' '`. Obviously there will be a space at the end...

Comment: Technically it works, but its the wrong output. Using rstrip(), will terminate all white spaces. I only need the last whitespace of the output to be deleted, all white spaces inbetween the letters should remain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove space at the end of an output in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519568/how-do-i-remove-space-at-the-end-of-an-output-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try list comprehension and join the resulting list, e.g.:

```
print(' '.join([data[letter] for letter in msg]))
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont quite understand why it worked when the for loop is in the print message but it did!

Comment: It's a shorthand way to create lists, very useful. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

To print a list joined by spaces, you can use the .join method.

To do this, try replacing the last 2 lines with this:

```py
morse_message = [data[letter] for letter in message]
print(" ".join(morse_message)
```

The first line makes a generator object (something I recommend looking into if you haven't already), and the 2nd line joins each character with a space without one at the end