# How to get rid of the last whitespace when printing with end=" "?

Tags: python, list, file

Task:
Create a solution that accepts an input identifying the name of a text file, for example, "WordTextFile1.txt". Each text file contains three rows with one word per row. Using the open() function and write() and read() methods, interact with the input text file to write a new sentence string composed of the three existing words to the end of the file contents on a new line. Output the new file contents.

The solution output should be in the format
cat
chases
dog
cat chases dog

the "WordTextFile1.txt" has only 3 words each in a different row
cat
chases
dog

This is what I have which works however the last line with the sentence has an extra whitespace which is breaking my program. What can I do to get rid of the whitespace and fix my code? Any help would be appreciated!

```
file = input()
with open(file, "r+") as f:
    list_words = f.readlines()

for word in list_words:
    print(word.strip())
for word in list_words:
    print(word.strip(), end = " ")    

this is current output:
student
reads
book
student reads book(extra whitespace)
```

Comment: Join first, then print.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove space at the end of an output in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519568/how-do-i-remove-space-at-the-end-of-an-output-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You are properly removing the last white space by `word.strip()` but adding `end = " "` just adds the last whitespace again. Change it to:

```
file = input()
with open(file, "r+") as f:
    list_words = f.readlines()
# I don't see any reason having this for loop
# for word in list_words:
#   print(word.strip())
print(' '.join(word.strip() for word in list_words) # this should work
```

**Edit:** Removed the list as it was not required. Thanks to @PranavHosangadi

Comment: `str.join` takes a generator expression, so you can save a loop by removing the `[` and `]`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Have things changed? I was told that it was better to have the list comprehension because a new string could be created of exactly the right size before copying the elements over.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```
    file = input()
    with open(file, 'r+') as f:
        WordTextFile = f.readlines()

        for words in WordTextFile:
            print(words.strip())

        for words in WordTextFile:
            print(words.strip(), end=' ')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That added white space issue gave me issues for a while, so I understand your pain. I tried to think outside the box with it and I ended up formatting my input as a list then spitting it out like that. Hope this helps.

```
file = input()

with open(file, 'r+') as x:
    conts= x.readlines() 
    for a in conts:
        print(a.strip())

with open(file, 'r+') as f:
    lines = []
    for i in f:
        i = i.strip()        
        lines.append(i)       
print(' '.join(lines))
```

Some links that will help:

[https://pythonhow.com/how/read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list/#:~:text=lines%20print(lines)-,To%20read%20a%20file%20line%2Dby%2Dline%20into%20a%20list,method%20of%20the%20file%20object.&text=In%20both%20cases%2C%20the%20list,of%20the%20file%20as%20elements](https://pythonhow.com/how/read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list/#:%7E:text=lines%20print(lines)-,To%20read%20a%20file%20line%2Dby%2Dline%20into%20a%20list,method%20of%20the%20file%20object.&text=In%20both%20cases%2C%20the%20list,of%20the%20file%20as%20elements).

https://www.entechin.com/how-to-print-a-list-without-square-brackets-in-python/#google_vignette